# RubyOnRails: Decoupling models and refactoring filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, design-patterns

In my Rails 4 app I have three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_question_results, dependent: :destroy
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_question_results, dependent: :destroy
end

class UserQuestionResult < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
end
```

On my Questions index page I want to show all questions in the system with results specific to the user, and filter questions depending on the results for each question. Eg:

- Question 1 - 0%, not started
- Question 2 - 25%, started
- etc

If I try something like `UserQuestionResult.where(user: user)` it returns, of course, questions with user results only, not all questions.

So I added this method to the Question class:

```
  def self.user_info(user)
    joins_sql = <<-SQL
      LEFT OUTER JOIN user_question_results
        ON questions.id=user_question_results.question_id
        AND user_question_results.user_id=#{user.id}
    SQL
    select_sql = <<-SQL
    questions.*,
    ifnull(user_question_results.percentage, 0) percentage,
    user_question_results.percentage IS NOT NULL as started
    SQL
    self.joins(joins_sql).select(select_sql)
  end
```

To use filters I added scopes to the Question model, like this:

```
  scope :user_correct, -> { where('percentage >= 99') }
```

So in my QuestionsController I user something like this:

```
Question.user_info(u).user_correct
```

It does work, but I wonder if there is a better solution. Especially, I'm worried about two points:

1. Question model got tightly coupled with the UserQuestionResult and User models.
2. Named scopes in the Question model depends would only work if `user_info` was called previously. It would break otherwise. I think it's a very bad design.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If an user hasn't answered a question, how come this question has anything to do with this user? Also, the naming seems weird. Would it be "Answer" instead of "QuestionResult"? A question can't have result, it can only have answer.

Comment: The user should see all the questions. Say, when he or she just registered, there are no results for that user. To be able to answer questions, he or she should see the questions. Later, when some answers are given, he or she should see all the questions again, but for the answered he or she should see their results.

As for the naming, there's the Answer model, but it has nothing to do with my question. There are several answers given by a user to a question. QuestionResult is calculated after each answer is given.